# Subtract one column from every column in a 2-d data array in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a 2D array of data that I need to re-zero. That is, I must subtract a column vector that I've calculated from each column in the matrix.

[image]

In math terms, if we define an "Identity Vector" where each element is 1, I need to do:

[image]

I've managed to shrink the matrix from 500k rows by a few hundred columns down to 160k rows by less than a hundred, but it is quite large and the handle drag stuff seems to crash Excel.

Comment: Do you have any RAND() or other volatile formulae in you data? This could be the reason for the crash. A simple subtraction shouldn't really break the bank. Slow yes, but not crash.

Comment: I have no formulae in the dataset until I add them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple cell by cell subtraction with the delta column vector "$"-locked would work for normal size data sets e.g.

```
=B2 - $I2
```

However it seems your problem is more related to the size of the data, and Excel crashing during a simple subtraction calculation. It could be that the amount of memory required simply exceeds what your computer has available. Here are some suggestions to try:

**1. Calculate from other sheet / workbook, with calculations on manual**

What if you put your zero'ing table in a new sheet/workbook, and putting calculations on manual? Prep the formulae in the new sheet:

=Sheet1!B2 - $I2

Copy and paste across, then press calculate.

**2. Try array formula, as Excel would do calculations in bulk**

Alternatively you can try to use array formula per column =(B2:B1000 - $I2:$I1000) and CTRL+SHFT+ENTER while selecting the whole output column L2:L1000. Not sure if it would really speed things up, but its worth a try.

**3. Save the file as an Excel binary file (*.xlsb)**

Saving the file in binary format may reduce memory requirements, or at least the processing load when saving the file or the auto backups. See here https://www.spreadsheet1.com/how-to-save-as-binary-excel-workbook.html

**4. Try using a cloud-based or alternative spreadsheet**

Try processing the data in Office Online or Google Sheets. Or try installing Open Office Calc?

**5. Use a 64-bit computer with a 64-bit version of Excel**

You can check what type of Windows (32 or 64 bit) you are running by pressing "windows button" + "Pause / Break". Check here to find out which type you are running from office https://www.howtogeek.com/288001/how-to-find-out-which-version-of-microsoft-office-youre-using/

**6. Set the undo stack depth to 0**

You could temporarily switch off undo by setting the undo stack depth to 0: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/211922/how-to-modify-the-number-of-undo-levels-in-excel

**7. Trust the file**

Also try adding the file location as a trusted zone in the trust centre. See here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4

**8. Don't use Excel**

As a last resort, process the data with Matlab or open alternatives like Octave or SciLab.

*/sad face/*

Comment: Excel seems to crash when I get about halfway done. Since I have 10 datasets each with 500k rows, this sort of thing doesn't seem to work. As far as the question goes, for the right size, your sugestion of ``=B2-$B2...`` is perfect.

Comment: How much ram/memory does you computer have? I would suggest you try hosting the second table in a second sheet but doubt that will if memory is the problem. I have two suggestions how to deal with the memory issue - will update my solution

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. A few notes. While the computer has 32GB of RAM, Excel only seems to use about 8 of those. Next, even after upgrading to 64-bit version and telling Excel to ignore other applications that use DDE, the operation still failed unless I closed and re-started Excel because (I believe) of the undo stack. That said, very good suggestions. and while I'm confused about why the operation took ~40 minutes, I did finish this stage of the work.

Comment: Glad it help somewhat. You could temporarily switch off undo by setting the undo stack depth to 0: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/211922/how-to-modify-the-number-of-undo-levels-in-excel

Comment: Also try adding the file location as a trusted location in the trust centre: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4